# How to make a new screen not totally covering the underlying screen on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a couple of `inputScreens` where user presses a button which currently opens another `pickerScreen with a picker and several buttons` on it.

Instead of showing the `pickerScreen` as a complete new screen that totally covers the `inputScreens` I would like the `pickerScreen` to show on top of the `inputScreen` -

> like a smaller screen centered and graying out and making inaccessible
>   the underlying `inputScreen` as long as the `pickerScreen` is shown.

Currently `inputScreens` and `pickerScreen` are implemented with UIViewController. ...and the `pickerScreen` totally replaces the `inputScreen`.

**Is there an easy way to just change the pickerScreen so it appears on top of the inputScreens?**

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a UIView with the picker view on it having the size as u desired.and hide that view in the view DidLoad.and when The desired button is pressed unhide that view.Then hide it after all your needs.it's so simple.otherwise adjust the size of the Pickerview as desired.`

```
UIView *whiteCoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
    whiteCoverView.alpha = 0.9;
    whiteCoverView.tag = 999;
    whiteCoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.view addSubview:whiteCoverView];




    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25, 320, 40)];
    label2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label2.numberOfLines = 0;
    label2.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
    label2.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    label2.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label2.text = @"cfff";
    [whiteCoverView addSubview:label2];
    [label2 release];

    int gap = 10;

    UILabel *label3a = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, gap+50, 280, 15)];
    label3a.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label3a.numberOfLines = 0;
    label3a.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13.0];
    label3a.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    label3a.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label3a.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label3a.text = @"cfccc ";
    [whiteCoverView addSubview:label3a];
    [label3a release];
```

add the picker like this.
`

Comment: thanks - but this won't grey out the underlying screen and also all the other elements of the underlying screen elements are still accessible...

Comment: do one thing...make a grey image background full sized view.and having the transparent parts in which you r going to add the pickers and all other things,and then add the picker view and all the buutons to that view.and do like what i said.so the backgrnd will be greyed..if need i will give u the code to make a transparent view ...

Comment: see the editted answer..like that u need add all your controlls.

Comment: ..I understand your approach, but this also does not make the underlying elements inaccessible and I would have to put all the code of my pickerScreen (basically all the buttons) in the inputScreen - all this I am trying to avoid - If there is no way to make the pickerScreen look like I described - I rather keep it the way it is now - many thanks though

Comment: see the editted answer.its will do the trick for u..still u r not getting only god can help u

Comment: again - thank you very much for the code - but as mentioned the underlying elements are all still accessible and all the code of pickerScreen would have to go into inputScreen. Ideally one could just change the pickerScreen to transparent and see the underlying inputScreen.. but as it seems this is only possible on Android - unfortunately not on iPhone...

Comment: how ..u r adding that picker to the grey view that has over the input screen.not to the self.view.is it then how can i click on the elements in the self view

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14393/discussion-between-user387184-and-bugfinder)

Comment: thanks - I have found that too - it uses ActionSheet which always is positioned on the buttom of the screen and does not behave like ViewController lifecycle - again, thanks very much but all I am looking for is a way to make the view of a ViewController smaller, so it can be spoitioned OVER some other and the remaining should ideally stay the same. In Android all that is necessary is to set a certain attribute of the screen, that's it - in iPhone there is no real convenient solution I guess+

Comment: my doubt always is why should u r not looking for a view inside a view controller